# Grouping PCA plots with colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I have a 106 x 105 dataset and of the 106 rows....73 are of type a and 33 are of type b
The columns refer to 105 different genes.

I've run PCA on the dataset using the commands:

```
pca1 = prcomp(data, scale. = TRUE)
plot(pca1$x, pch = 20)
```

However I want the plot to show the type a points in red and the type b points in blue and I don't really know how to do this

I tried doing this:

```
groups <- c(rep(1,73),rep(2,33))
qplot(pca1$x,colour = groups)
```

but this returned the error message

```
"Error: Aesthetics must either be length one or the same length as the data.
 Problems:groups"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switched from base graphics to `ggplot2` graphics w/o making the necessary changes.  `ggplot2` requires a data frame as the input.  And `pca1$x` is a matrix, not a data frame.  `ggplot2` will try to guess an aesthetic, but in this case it doesn't know that you want to plot the PC1 scores against the PC2 scores (since the matrix is no. samples x no. variables).  So you need to do something along these lines (untested since you didn't give us data):

```
df <- as.matrix(pca1$x)
df$groups <- c(rep(1,73),rep(2,33))
str(df) # so you can see the structure and names
qplot(x = name of 1st column, y = name of 2nd column, data = df, geom = "point", color = 'groups')
```

Give us some sample data and we can be more specific.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use base graphics, then just add a vector of color names to your original plot call:

```
plot(pca1$x, pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 73), rep("blue", 33)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using the simple plot() function instead of qplot?

Here's some sample data:

data = [Type Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4
         a     2.4   4.6   8.1   1.33 
         a     4.4   3.1  2.6    50   
         b     15   -4.1   5.6   80
         b     -2.1  3.2    14.2  45.3]

Comment: Check the edit above.  And for future reference, to provide some sample data, one easy way is to do `dput(head(your_data_object))` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: That's great, much appreciated. Will remember that in future. Is there a way of adding a legend to the plot to say that the red dots are type a and the blue dots are type b?

Comment: Certainly, see `?legend`.  Legends can get tricky, but yours should be straightforward.  In general, using base graphics can require a lot of tweaking to get things the way one wants them.  Packages like `ggplot2` take care of lots of little things for you in logical ways, so it's worth learning if you'll be doing much plotting.  If my answer has solved your problem, please look for a checkmark in the left margin and click it to accept the answer.  That way people know the question has been handled and I get reputation points so I can take over the world.